# LWC Code Splitting/Bundling Strategy

Tags: lightning-web-components, package

Does anyone have any knowledge or resources describing how salesforce splits lwc code into bundle?

If I have a large 1MB lwc, and it is used in several other lwcs, does salesforce extract that large lwc into a common bundle, or is some other strategy used?

Comment: Did you find anything on this? If not, could you improve the question with more details?